# Leaflet marker display Issues with css framework and using panes

Tags: css, leaflet

I am using the combination of Leaflet and the Bulma css to create a web page.
Bulma like many other frameworks seems to reset some classes that mess with Leaflet.
Mainly

```
max-width: 100%
```

inside the img class.
Leaflet is supposed to fix that as per this github issue:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5775
However I ran into it even with the current release.
I created a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/FiddleHeimer3000/n9k53mcy/17/ to illustrate the problem.

here three markers get created:

```
var markyMcMarkface_a = new L.marker(new L.LatLng( 1752,2136 ),{
        title:"Hello Kitty A",
        pane:"left"
}).addTo(map);
var markyMcMarkface_b = new L.marker(new L.LatLng( 1752,3300 ),{
        title:"Hello Kitty B",
        pane:"right"
}).addTo(map)
var markyMcMarkface_c = new L.marker(new L.LatLng( 1352,3300 ),{
        title:"Hello Kitty C",
}).addTo(map)
```

Now with the bulma.css present only the last marker, which is not attached to a pane gets rendered.
Once the bulma.css with the max-width: 100% is omitted all works well.
What I dont understand is that the leaflet fix:

```
.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg, 
.leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img, 
.leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img, 
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img, 
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer { 
    max-width: none !important; 
}
```

does not seem to work at all.
Tried in all current browsers.
Any CSS wiz around to shine a light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working version for you: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/4ycv5eum/

You have to add the markers to the sideBySide layer array:

```
L.control.sideBySide([left_layer,markyMcMarkface_a],[right_layer,markyMcMarkface_b]).addTo(map);
```

And add this css:

```
.leaflet-pane.leaflet-left-pane, .leaflet-pane.leaflet-right-pane{
  z-index: 599;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a more complicated example where this does not work, unfortunately. 
Will try to find time for a distilled version as a fiddle to see if that can be solved.